# why does my conda deactivate doesn't work?

Tags: python, conda, environment

I am having troubles with my conda installation on a cluster. It seems that i can't deactivate any of my environments. it goes so far, that i have to close my terminal because it froze.

I am working on multiple server with a common home directory, so i can access the same conda installation from different servers. Interestingly, I can deactivate the conda envs on a different server,  but not on my main server, which i work most of the time.

I use conda 22.9.0

I there a way to solve this without reinstalling everything?
(Can I reinstall conda itself without loosing the already set environments?)

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Give us some insight by putting your terminal outputs.

Comment: Not really sure what to put. This is why I didn't add anything. I have added a pic of what i see.  Activating is not a problem, but deactivating freezes the screen

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11885. You shouldn't need to reinstall Conda. Instead, clean out the `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`) and then try rerunning `conda init`. Issues with `conda activate` or `deactivate` are almost always about shell initialization files, not about Conda Python package. Worst case, downgrade `conda` to `4.14`.

Comment: thanks, a simple `conda init bash` seems to do the trick for now. Let's see if it stays.

Comment: using powershell can be cause of this issue. Try to kill this terminal and open a cmd terminal. Then try conda deactivate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

thanks to @merv I could easily solve the problem.

Running `conda init bash` and restarting the terminal seems to clean something and now it works as well.
I can see again my prompt and the environments are closing again.

```
yeroslaviz@hpcl8001:~$ conda init bash
modified      /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/condabin/conda
modified      /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/bin/conda
modified      /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/bin/activate
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /fs/home/yeroslaviz/.bashrc

==> For changes to take effect, close and re-open your current shell. <==

yeroslaviz@hpcl8001:~$ exit

yeroslaviz@hpcl8001:~$ conda activate base
(base) yeroslaviz@hpcl8001:~$ 
(base) yeroslaviz@hpcl8001:~$ conda deactivate
yeroslaviz@hpcl8001:~$
```